# How to enable remote debugging with headless chrome when using ruby and selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

When I set the option "--remote-debugging-port", it will throw an error. And without this option, it can work properly. However, I want to debug when using the headless chrome. How can I do ?

.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

Here is my code:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port') # debug
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
puts @driver.manage.logs.get :browser
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [**Getting Started with Headless Chrome**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) to enable **remote-debugging** you can add the argument **`remote-debugging-port`** through `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new` which will help in:

> Navigating to http://localhost:9222 in another browser to open the DevTools interface or use a tool such as Selenium to drive the headless browser.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
puts @driver.manage.logs.get :browser
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case for some reason, it changed automatically to other port(61625), even setting the port to 922 in add_argument. I had to look in cli log to notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the code in selenium python but didn't work. I used `options.add_argument('--headless')` then `options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')` but the bot is still visible.